# Passing non-POD types as __global__ function parameters in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I know that non-POD types can't be passed as parameters to CUDA kernel launches in general.
But where I can find an explanation for this, I mean a reliable source like a book, a CUDA manual, etc.

Comment: On what basis do you do know that? It is completely incorrect. You are free to pass any complete type as an argument, either by reference or by value (there is a limit of 255 bytes or 4k for the total size of the argument list, but that is the only restriction). Don't cofuse non-portability of host and device pointers with restrictions on types.

Comment: i meant when i try to pass a class, i can't access to the class functions, just access the data stored.

Comment: But you can access class methods in device code, **if those methods are valid `__device__` functions**. Have a look at the way the thrust library uses functors for valid examples of this.

Comment: oh i see, so i have to define like a device function. still where i can find a book about this, especially when working with predefined classes like stack.h . (i don't have many experience with cuda)

Comment: @talonmies If you will post an answer to this question I will upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire premise of this question is incorrect. CUDA kernel arguments are not limited to POD types.

You are free to pass any complete type as an argument, either by reference or by value. There is a limit of 255 bytes or 4kb for the total size of the argument list depending on which architecture you compile for, but that is the only restriction on kernel arguments. When passing an instance of a class to a CUDA kernel, there are a number of simple restrictions which you must follow, including:

1. Any pointers in the class instance which the device code will dereference must be valid device pointers
2. Any member functions in the class which the the device code will call must be valid `__device__` functions
3. Is it illegal to pass a class containing virtual functions or derived from a virtual base type as as a kernel argument
4. Classes which access namespace anonymous unions are not supported in device code

All of the features and limitations of C++ support in CUDA kernel code is described in the [CUDA Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#c-cplusplus-language-support), a copy of which ships in every version of the CUDA toolkit. All you need to do is read it.